# html2pdf PHP generates an additional blank page

Tags: php, laravel, pdf-generation, html2pdf

I use html2pdf to generate pdf with table data but I have some issue that I can't deal with. No matter how I set margins i always have some additional blank page at the end of pdf. 
This is how looks like my pdf template :

```
<body>
<div class="page">
    <div class="inner-page">
        <div class="dealers-table">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="it">Lp.</div>
                <div class="name">Name</div>
                <div class="street">street</div>
                <div class="post-code">Post Code</div>
                <div class="city">City</div>
                <div class="phone">Phone</div>
                <div class="services">Services</div>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <div>
                    <div class="it"></div>
                    <div class="name"></div>
                    <div class="street"></div>
                    <div class="post-code"></div>
                    <div class="city"></div>
                    <div class="phone"></div>
                    <div class="services"> /</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.page {
  width: 210mm;
  height: 280mm;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-page {
  padding: 5mm 10mm;
}

.dealers-table {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 6.5pt;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

I don't set any margins in options of my Converter.

When I set page width less than 280px table from second page starts at the end of first page and additional blank page doesn't appear, in other situations there is always useless blank page.

How can I fix it?

**EDIT 1**

There is some code where I generate pdf on server side:

```
public function generatePdf() {

    $autoDealers = $this->autoDealersOrServices(0); 
(some function where i fetch array of dealers from my DB)

     $autoDealers = view('pdf.template', [
        'autoDealers' => $autoDealers
        ])->render();


        $input = new StringInput();
        $input->setHtml($view);

        $converter = new Converter($input, new FileOutput());
        $converter->setOption('landscape', false);
        $converter->setOptions([
            'printBackground' => true
        ]);

        $output = $converter->convert();
        $output->store('pdf/auto/dealers.pdf');
  }
```

Comment: I do not think that this is an error in your HTML. Please provide server side code.

Comment: @KiprasT I added code of my function where I generate pdf

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/issues/318#issuecomment-380483469), maybe it will fix you issue

Answer (score 0):

SyntaxEditor Code Snippet

`"--encoding UTF-8 --page-size A4 --margin-left 10 --margin-right 10 --margin-top 20 --margin-bottom 0"`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: @alels.ko Thank you for answer but I don't understand, what do you suggest to do?